# Rails + Mongoid slow queries in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, mongodb, mongoid

I'm running into some performance issues with my Mongoid queries, specifically in production. 
My initial though was that it had something to do with the hosting (was on the smallest Linode instance) but when I migrated to a bigger instance, the query speeds got marginally better. For comparison sake, a product page would take around 800ms - 1000ms to load in production (60ms in development) but after the hosting migration, it hovers around 300ms - 800ms in production. This leads me to believe that the slowness is caused by inefficient queries along with possible n+1 side effects. Here is a snapshot of what happens when I hit my products API:

```
MOPED: 173.255.252.208:27017 QUERY database=* collection=orders selector=    {"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"52cc529eec5cb38bbf000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1   skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (20.6976ms)
MOPED: 173.255.252.208:27017 QUERY database=* collection=orders selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"52cc529eec5cb38bbf000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (13.5436ms)
MOPED: 173.255.252.208:27017 COMMAND      database=* command={:count=>"orders", :query=>{"user_id"=>"52cc529eec5cb38bbf000001"}} (18.1813ms)
MOPED: 173.255.252.208:27017 QUERY        database=* collection=orders selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"52cc529eec5cb38bbf000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (15.9233ms)
MOPED: 173.255.252.208:27017 QUERY        database=* collection=orders selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"52cc529eec5cb38bbf000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (29.9242ms)
MOPED: 173.255.252.208:27017 QUERY        database=* collection=orders selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"52cc529eec5cb38bbf000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (69.3288ms)
```

It seems like this is the bulk of what's causing the slowness, however, why would querying the Orders collection be so slow? Below is the stats() from Mongodb:

```
db.orders.stats()
{
    "ns" : "orders",
    "count" : 21535,
    "size" : 15068736,
    "avgObjSize" : 699.7323426979336,
    "storageSize" : 23617536,
    "numExtents" : 7,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 9555968,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.025000000000004,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 5567856,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 711312,
        "order_number_index" : 972944,
        "_keywords_1" : 3883600
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The collection itself seems pretty small (22k records) so it's confusing as to why the queries are so slow. As you can see, I've added indexes on the collection so I'm stuck as to what I can do to improve query speed. Help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What Mongo version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're querying on orders by user_id, it might be a good idea to add an index on user_id. Indexing `{ user_id: 1 }` should be fine.

If you posted the related code inside your app, it would be easier to tell if it's an n+1 query. However, it does look like it might be, since you're querying the orders collection multiple times; a more efficient query would be selecting orders where the user_id is in an array of user_ids. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#eager-loading) for the mongoid docs on eager loading. Essentially, if you're iterating over orders by user with something like `User.all.each { |u| puts u.orders }`, you could make it much more efficient by simply adding `.includes(:orders)` before the `.each`.

If you're still having slowness issues, it might be worthwhile to take the line(s) of code that are querying the database and run `.explain` on them in the console. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/) for help on understanding the results, or [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/cursor.explain/) if you're on 2.6 instead of 3.0. The most important thing to look at is the number of documents that are being scanned versus the number of documents that match the criteria in the output. For instance, if you have 21535 documents and no index on user_id, you're probably scanning all 21535 documents every time to find one that matches that user_id. Once you've added indexes, `.explain` will show you if you're using the index under the plans section.